# Joining tables with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, `testimonials` and `area`.

`Testimonials` has a *one to many* relationship with `area`. I basically want to use *Eloquent* to create the following *SQL* query:

`SELECT * FROM  'testimonial' INNER JOIN area ON  'area_id' = area.id`

My models looks like this:

```
class Area extends \Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'area';

    public function testimonials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Testimonials');
    }


}

class Testimonial extends \Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'testimonial';

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Area');
    }

}
```

I thought that in my route I could just do this to return all `testimonial`s and their `area`s

```
$testimonial = Testimonial::all();
```

however it doesn't work as expected. This should be simple, but everything I have tried hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Testimonial::with('area')->get();
```